# What is Microsoft's GWT solution for .NET?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, gwt, script#

I like GWT but I prefer to use ASP.NET MVC for my projects, however, these two are not integrated and require me to write my code in two different platforms and two languages. Does Microsoft have any solutions comparable to GWT for compiling C# into JavaScript? I know there is Script# which is not supported by MS and the Volta project which was killed after its preview, but I was wondering if there is any good solutions available now or at least some good open source project that can integrate ASP.NET with GWT. Thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify the question? Are you asking for an easy way to mix ASP.NET with GWT, or are you asking about a comprehensive GWT-like, Microsoft-compatible solution that doesn't actually use GWT?

Comment: I'm asking what do .NET developers suggest for bringing GWT or GWT-like functionality in ASP.NET? In other words what is the suggested approach to have Compile Time Checking for developing client-side code (Java or C#) and at the same time having ASP.NET MVC on the server side?

Comment: I think Microsoft is into TypeScript (https://www.typescriptlang.org/) - which gives you compile-time type safety and it is still very close to javascript.

Comment: @OndrejSvejdar TypeScript is today the correct answer and I've been using it for a couple years now. I will mark as answer if anyone posts about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Bridge.NET](http://bridge.net/) is in this space. It describes itself as:

> Open Source C# to JavaScript Compiler and Frameworks. 
>   Run Your App On Any Device Using JavaScript.

The Microsoft driven solution is [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) which is a separate language made with input from the lead architect of C#, Anders Hejlsberg. It is also open source.

Answer (score 10):

Well, I can tell you what my preferred stack looks like these days. To me it is a nice balance of established tech with flexibility, though keep in mind I use this mostly to build single-page ajax "apps", not for the traditional collection of pages.

- [Sharp UI](https://github.com/duckmaestro/Sharp-UI) (full disclosure: this is one of my open source projects)
- [Script#](https://github.com/nikhilk/scriptsharp)
- [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)
- I use a tool I wrote internally for generating "packet" classes shared by WCF and Script#.
- WCF (in JSON)
- ASP.NET (either Webforms or MVC)

I get compile-time type checking from Script#, UI control encapsulation from Sharp UI, fairly easy to maintain JSON service endpoints through WCF and my code generation tool, and ASP.NET for misc or traditional web pages. I'm firing on all 8 cylinders with this setup.

Comment: Can you talk more about how you orchestrate the jquery-UI stuff, or do you not use that?

Comment: The Script# link is dead

Answer (score 4):

Good suggestion, but as AFAIK there is absolutely nothing like GWT in the .Net world.

I'm a Java and .Net programmer.  I've battled infrequently with javascript for about 3 years, and never become comfortable with it.  Since adopting GWT I'm producing Javascript=based web pages but coding in Java - I absolutely adore it ;-)

There's no great reason why there can't be a .Net equivalant of GWT.  GWT doesn't do a 'literal copy' of Java to produce the Javascript - so it doesn't rely on the two languages having a 'similar' grammer.  Any language could be converted.  Mind you, it would take a lot of effort to duplicate the analysis and optimisation performed by the GWT compiler in producing it's js files.

A more effective route may be to find a C# to Java converter, and then pass the output to GWT.

Comment: I give you even better: C# => Ruby => Fortran => **Chuck Norris** => VB => ASP => PHP => J2E => Java => GWT... **FTW!** Where can I help? ;)

Comment: @Robert Koritnik : this is the best answer EVER! ROFTL!

Comment: Maybe one could try C# => IKVM => GWT

Answer (score 3):

SharpKit for C# .NET is like GWT but actually does much more.  They even have a CLR written entirely in Javascript that provides Reflection, Generics, etc. on the client.

http://sharpkit.net

Comment: Thanks, SharpKit seemed to be inactive for some time but looks like they are in business again. However, as for Microsoft's supported solution that can compare to GWT I chose [TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/) although it's not exactly C# to JavaScript.